# Automatically show keyboard on first render of react-native-confirmation-code-field

Tags: reactjs, react-native, password-confirmation

I am using the react-native-confirmation-code-field [package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxnRm.png).  I want the keyboard to be showing as soon as the screen renders and the first cell in focus.  Any ideas how to do this?

[image]

**Edit**:  Including my code below:

```
export default function ConfirmationCode({ route, navigation }) {

  const [value, setValue] = useState("")
  const ref = useBlurOnFulfill({ value, cellCount: CELL_COUNT })
  const [props, getCellOnLayoutHandler] = useClearByFocusCell({value, setValue})

  return (
        <CodeField
          ref={ref}
          {...props}
          value={value}
          onChangeText={setValue}
          cellCount={CELL_COUNT}
          rootStyle={styles.codeFieldRoot}
          keyboardType="number-pad"
          textContentType="oneTimeCode"
          renderCell={({ index, symbol, isFocused }) => (
            <Text
              key={index}
              style={[styles.cell, isFocused && styles.focusCell]}>
              {symbol || (isFocused ? <Cursor /> : null)}
            </Text>
          )
          }
        />
    )
}
```

Comment: the key is to focus on the first cell, I think you will need to use Ref

Comment: thanks @FaysalB.  i'm still not sure how to do it.  have included my code above if you can give more explicit guidance?

Comment: I just had some playing around in the library, unfortunately you have to change the core features of the library to do the wanted, I would just use another one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out that CodeField does have an autoFocus property, my bad.  The solution is simply to add autoFocus={true} as a prop to the CodeField component:

```
        <CodeField
          ref={ref}
          {...props}
          autoFocus={true}
          value={value}
          onChangeText={setValue}
          cellCount={CELL_COUNT}
          rootStyle={styles.codeFieldRoot}
          keyboardType="number-pad"
          textContentType="oneTimeCode"
          renderCell={({ index, symbol, isFocused }) => (
            <TextInput
              key={index}
              ref={index === 0 && textInputRef)
              style={[styles.cell, isFocused && styles.focusCell]}>
              {symbol || (isFocused ? <Cursor /> : null)}
            </TextInput>
          )
          }
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `Text` component to `TextInput`. But make sure it is disabled.
Set a ref(you would need the first one).

And on `useEffect`, call the `focus` method on that ref.

Roughly, it should look something like this:

```
export default function ConfirmationCode({ route, navigation }) {

  const [value, setValue] = useState("")
  const ref = useBlurOnFulfill({ value, cellCount: CELL_COUNT })
  const [props, getCellOnLayoutHandler] = useClearByFocusCell({value, setValue})


 const textInputRef = useRef(null);

 useEffect(() => {
      textInputRef.current?.focus()      
}, []);
    
  return (
        <CodeField
          ref={ref}
          {...props}
          value={value}
          onChangeText={setValue}
          cellCount={CELL_COUNT}
          rootStyle={styles.codeFieldRoot}
          keyboardType="number-pad"
          textContentType="oneTimeCode"
          renderCell={({ index, symbol, isFocused }) => (
            <TextInput
              key={index}
              ref={index === 0 && textInputRef)
              style={[styles.cell, isFocused && styles.focusCell]}>
              {symbol || (isFocused ? <Cursor /> : null)}
            </TextInput>
          )
          }
        />
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks @hasn.  Your answer led me to look into the autoFocus property, and it turns out that CodeField has an autoFocus property on its own, pity it is not stated anywhere in the docs!